# How to generate request to the ADFS, get session and authenticate user on Django server?

Tags: python, django, authentication, single-sign-on, adfs

I'm configure Web SSO authentication by using ADFS on [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378921(v=ws.10).aspx) guide. Му back-end developed using Django. How to generate Django request for user authentication? As I understand request looks like this.:

*decoded:* adfsresource.treyresearch.net/adfs/ls/auth/integrated/?wa=wsignin1.0&**wreply**=https://adfsweb.treyresearch.net/claimapp/&**wct**=2016-07-27T14:58:30Z&**wctx**=5f64b4e7-8907-47df-9526-5450b4ce0660

How generate **wctx** on django?
I'm found:

> Wctx: This is some session data that the application wants sent back
>   to it after the user authenticates. How generate **wctx** on django

What protocols using in this process (to adfs and back)?

ADFS 1.1, django 1.9.7, firefox

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use directly the SAML protocol?. ADFS supports SAML and I think is easier to setup than ws-fed (and also more adopted).

You will need to add SAML support to the django app, in order to do that you have 2 alternatives:

- [django-saml-service-provider](https://github.com/KristianOellegaard/django-saml-service-provider) (uses [python-saml](https://github.com/onelogin/python-saml) library)
- [djangosaml2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/djangosaml2) (uses [pysaml2](https://github.com/rohe/pysaml2) library)

Both are well documented.

Info about how configure ADFS as SAML Identity Provider [here](http://support.talentlms.com/knowledgebase/articles/328229-how-to-configure-sso-with-microsoft-active-directo)

Other alternative is to use [Oauth2](https://github.com/jobec/django-auth-adfs).

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I'm install adfs 2.0 and try configure it. Help me configure serviceprovider.xml for RPTrust for django. Xml is something terrible!

Comment: The serviceprovider.xml is the metadata of the Service Provider (django) and its autogenerated.